# Is it ok to create object in DAO

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory, dao

I have a DAO, for example, for accessing database of tokens.
Is it OK to use it to create and immediately persist new entities, like in the example below? (sample in PHP)

```
class TokenDao {
    ...
    public function createToken($code) {
        $token = new Token($code);
        $this->entityManager->persist($token);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        return $token;
    }
}
```

It combines an object factory with DAO a bit. I think making separate object factory and dao (and probably wrapping into facade) is unnecessary overhead, but I'd like to hear from others if this isn't a bad practice.

I haven't found any positive or negative clues over articles about DAO pattern if this is ok or not.

Thanks for opinions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

In My opinion a DAO should be only used to encapsulate the database not perform some logic or creation.

In your example, another problem is if you change the Token constructor, you will have to change the TokenDao as well.

My opinion, create the token in a separate layer from your DAO.